# this.props.match.params.vendor_id giving undefined value

Tags: reactjs, react-router

i am sending vendor id in url and it is showing in url like http://localhost:3000/#/base/property/1 but when i console.log(id) it shows undefined

```js
const Id = this.props.match.params.vendor_id;
    console.log(Id);
```

```html
<Link to={"property/"+product.vendor_id}><Button block color="secondary" className="btn-pill">{product.num}</Button></Link>
```

Comment: Hi Nilesh. Just wrote you an answer, let me know if this helpful to you.

Comment: Can you show how have you configured your Route and in which component you are using the params

Comment: { path: '/base/property:vendor_id', component: Forms } this is how i am configuring routes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe you have the incorrect syntax in your `Link` defiintion. Try using backticks instead

```
<Link to={`/property/${product.vendor_id}`}><Button block color="secondary" className="btn-pill">{product.num}</Button></Link>
```

Also check that you have constructed this Route to accept a wildcard of `vendor_id`, otherwise you will always get undefined.

```
<Route path="/property/:vendor_id" component={yourComponent}/>
```

Comment: Hello Christopher Thanks for the answer but when i use the backticks it gives me an error  Line 149:  Parsing error: JSX value should be either an expression or a quoted JSX text

Comment: Oh sorry about that Nilesh. I forgot we need to wrap the back ticks in curly braces. See above.

Comment: it solved my problem but still I am getting undefined as the value in the console. please help although the url shows me the id

Comment: Hmm can you do me a favor? Can you post the component that contains this code: const Id = this.props.match.params.vendor_id;.      Also, can you share your React-router-dom code that sets up all the routes?

Comment: the component and the route file has too much of code sorry will not able to post that thanks for helping me :)

Comment: Ah. Well I definitely think it's something up with your Routers file, so let me know if there's anything you need help with and if you'd like to take this discussion offline.

Comment: ok are you on skype please share me your username if it is possible

Comment: Thank you Christopher you were right i was not passing the vendor_id in routes it solved my problem :) happy coding

Comment: Hey sorry about that! I spent the last 20 minutes trying to download Skype lol. I can't believe its not free anymore :(. But anyway, I'm glad that worked for you!